# System.Exception: MobileControl must be contained within a MobilePage: ASP.webform1_aspx

Tags: asp.net, controls, mobile

Hi I am getting this exception while running the mobile form page in asp.net. its script is :

```
    <mobile:Label id="lblCriteriaA" runat="server">Hi all</mobile:Label>
    <mobile:Label id="lblCriteriaB" runat="server"></mobile:Label>
    <mobile:SelectionList id="slstMovies" runat="server"></mobile:SelectionList>
    <mobile:Command id="bttnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="showData">Show Times</mobile:Command>
    <mobile:TextView ID="TextView1" Runat="server">TextView</mobile:TextView>
```

Is something wrong in this design script ? And what if I want to write code at server side then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that your server controls are inside a  tag.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication_ASPMobile.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mobile" Namespace="System.Web.UI.MobileControls" Assembly="System.Web.Mobile, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>

  <mobile:Form id=Form1 runat="server">

     <mobile:Label id="lblCriteriaA" runat="server">Hi all</mobile:Label>
     <mobile:Label id="lblCriteriaB" runat="server"></mobile:Label>
     <mobile:SelectionList id="slstMovies" runat="server"></mobile:SelectionList>
     <mobile:Command id="bttnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="showData">Show Times</mobile:Command>
     <mobile:TextView ID="TextView1" Runat="server">TextView</mobile:TextView>
  </mobile:form>
```

Comment: ummm... ok! but then what should the script there ?

Comment: This will not work dear, It needs MobileForm as container tag rather than normal form tag.

Comment: working...............! But must is this, code behind of this aspx must be inherits from "System.Web.UI.MobileControls.MobilePage"